# Story like Jurassic Park but with megafauna; mammoths and sabre-tooth tigers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story (or novelette ?) only about ten years ago, in a collection that might have been much older.

(sorry, I had typed novella, but it was certainly not one, just possibly a rather shortish novelette if not a short story)

Progress in genetics have allowed to reconstruct the megafauna that early humans have hunted to extinction, so they still existed up to just a few tens of millennia ago or less: mammoths, woolly rhinoceroses, cave bears, saber-toothed tigers, huge lions...

There are also augmented humans, with special abilities.

The action takes place in a nature reserve for this megafauna. Its Director is precisely one of these 'augmented humans'. He was given, through genetic manipulation, special talents as a leader but he chose to become a scientist instead with no more responsibilities than this reserve and its staff.

So the President of whatever country the reserve was in (US? Canada? both having merged by then?) asked for a tour of the Reserve, guided specially by the Director, not by anyone else. In fact this is a false pretense. What the President really wants is to evaluate him as a natural leader. Satisfied, he offers him some very high political (or maybe military) position.

Though the Director had chosen to be a scientist rather than a leader, he feels that his genetic modifications somehow fight against his earlier decision, he feels something pushing him to accept almost against himself.

I forgot who won this internal fight, free decision or genetic destiny.

Comment: You've put several phrases in quote marks ("Jurassic Park", "Augmented Humans"). Were these specific phrases used in the story?

Comment: @Valorum "Jurassic Park" is **not at all** in the story. It is just something I made up myself for the title of my question for people to have a vague idea before reading the full question. The quote marks for  "augmented human" are also mine precisely because I do not remember the **exact phrase** used in the story. Genetic manipulations have created humans with, not superhuman powers, but just specific special abilities, like leader qualities in this case. But this genetic conditioning interacts with free decision.

Comment: megafauna, mammoths, and sabre-tooth tigers. Oh My!

Comment: @FreeMan I checked, but it is not in Oz, alas.... No yellow brick road, no ruby slippers. Though IIRC, the President is about as honest as a famous Wizard... ROTFLOL